# Assets\Score.cs(10,16): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.Text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

Error: Assets\Score.cs(10,16): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration

[Here is the picture of da error of my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjt7D.jpg)

pls help me

Comment: Are you sure that this is really the contents of `Score.cs`? If it is, did you forget to save?

Comment: The code you posted here would not reproduce this error .. double check for typos ... one is for instance `scoreText.Text` should rather be `scoreText.text` but that would give you a different error ;)